# ng-messages-include not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularjs and trying to create a form with some validation messages using `ng-messages` and `ng-messages-include`.

When I write inline error messages using `ng-messages` it works, but when I use `ng-messages-include` and refer to a remote file it does not work. 
Below is the code.

**messages.html**

```
<div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
```

**form.html**

```
</div>
        <div ng-messages="form.name.$error" style="color:red" ng-if="form.name.$dirty" ng-messages-include="pages/html/messages.html">
  <!--  <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>-->
 </div>
```

If I uncomment the code above it works fine, but with `ng-messages-include` it does not work. 
Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide a pen/bin please, more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it working. The ng-messages-include has to be a child on the div.

```
</div>
    <div ng-messages="form.name.$error" style="color:red" ng-if="form.name.$dirty">
<div ng-messages-include="pages/html/messages.html"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Double-check that the messages.html is actually loading.  Maybe your URL is wrong?  Maybe it needs to have a "/" character at the beginning to start at the root directory?

You can check if it's loading by opening the developer console by pressing F12 in your browser.  Check the "Network" tab and look for the file "messages.html".  I suspect your problem is there.

Comment: messages.html is not being loaded. i tried adding a '/' at the beginning of the path also, but no luck. :-( .

Comment: Then the problem is the URL or the location of the file on the server.  Make sure that the file actually exists on the server and check that it's location is the same as your URL path.